# Horror movie where buried people and animals come back to life

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie 8 to 9 years ago. It was a color movie.

The story goes like this: There was a doctor who moved to a new house with his family, his wife, two children a girl and a boy and his daughter's pet cat. When his family went to visit grandmother, doctor remained in the house with cat. The cat died in a road accident and he couldn't tell his daughter about cat. Then his neighbour took him to a land to bury the cat.

Next day cat returned from grave alive but behaved oddily. That land was cursed. When his family arrived his son also died in a road accident. After burial when his rest of the family returned to grandmother's house, doctor dug open his son's grave and again buried him in cursed land. When his son return he killed the neighbour.

His wife return and his son killed her and also tried to kill his father. But his father finally killed his son. But again buried his wife in the cursed land. His wife came back and killed him.

I couldn't remember the name of the movie - what is it?

Answer (score 25):

You're looking for [Pet Sematary 1989](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098084/)

> Behind a young family's home in Maine is a terrible secret that holds
>   the power of life after death. When tragedy strikes, the threat of
>   that power soon becomes undeniable.

In this movie, a family moves to a town. Their family cat gets hit by a truck and the father feels bad for the daughter who is devastated by this, so he buries it in a cemetery that used to be used by the ancient Indians. The cat comes back to life, but is not the same as it was before.

Then the baby boy dies. The father buries him in the same place and he comes back and tries to kill everyone. Then the father buries the wife and she comes back and kills the father.

Comment: There's also the amazing book by Stephen King, which the movie is based upon.

Comment: Don't forget the Ramones song, which can be found on the soundtrack to the movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3J0iwwsq-w